# Raspberry Pi how to trigger event on pull-down interrupt pin

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, microcontroller, interrupt, raspberry-pi2

I have a sensor with the interrupt output connected to a input pin on my RaspberryPi. My goal is to trigger an event from the sensor interrupt. The data sheet for my sensor says that once an interrupt is triggered on the sensor, the interrupt status register will have the appropriate bit set to 1 and stay that way until it is cleared; while the status register has a status bit of 1, the interrupt pad on the sensor will be pulled down.

My problem is that I can see the status register correctly reflect an interrupt when I physically trigger the sensor. But when I read the pin from my Pi, I never see any change reflected. Here's the gist of my code:

```
import Sensor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

s = Sensor.start()

while True:
    print 'sensor int reg: ', s.readIntReg() # I do not clear interrupt
    print 'pin value: ', GPIO.input(11)
```

The first print will change according to my interaction with the sensor as expected. The second print shows the pin holds 1 or 0 depending on whether it is set to pull up or down, respectively.

It seems like the problem lies in that whenever the interrupt fires, the sensor is pulling the pin down and the Pi is pulling it up... How should I handle this?

The sensor is the VCNL4010 [https://www.adafruit.com/products/466]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the gpio driver installed and active on the Pi?

Then you'll probably never see the interrupt triggering from the Python level since the kernel driver will service it (and reset the flag) already in the background.

Comment: For testing I haven't configured the pin to trigger an interrupt on the Pi. It's just an input that I'm polling so I can see it change values based on the sensor interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I added a 10k external pull-up resistor with 3.3V and that did the trick... not sure why the internal pull-up on the Pi didn't do the same, perhaps I configured it wrong.

UPDATE: That turned out not to be the issue at all. I was neglecting to explicitly set the sensor to free run mode. Part of my code had the unintended side effect of setting that mode so in tweaking things for test sometimes it worked. The pull-up on the Pi works fine.